# Wifi connected but no internet on MacBook Air 1,1 2008 (or working but unstable) - stable fix

Tags: wifi, macintosh, broadcom

There is a recurrent and very much difficult to solve instability of the wifi connection on the 2008 MacBook Air due to the chipset, causing various trouble on Ubuntu ranging from

connection to Wifi but no connectivity
keyboard and mouse lacking
irq conflicts
What happened is that each time the connection seems to work again, but after some time there is a connection, but no internet, and the compatibility issue is such that the previous found solutions don't work anymore!

I'll propose here a workaround supplying a stable solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this question and answer has been moved from AskUbuntu since violating rules by mentionning non official Ubuntu flavors.

After struggling a lot, knowing there are solutions around, that I found in Linux Mint forums, but not giving a stable solution for the problem.

I refer to this thread, however the solution is not entirely solved there.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007852/how-to-get-internal-wifi-working-on-macbook-air-1-1-on-ubuntu-mate-16-04

"To resolve this issue you must re-install Linux Mint, Debian, Ubuntu, etc.

Begin the reinstallation process and where you select "Installation Type" select "Something Else"
create a 500MB partition and select "reverse bios" instead of "efi"

To the best of my knowledge, problem seems to be that "Secure Boot" AKA "efi" only allows for supported hardware and the required b43 driver apparently isn't supported hardware."
Source: [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=223778&sid=a78b7ecfcfb642aa2b77ab1662baba12&start=20)

Then, just install the b43-installer from driver manager.

If you prefer an out of the box solution, there are other, Ubuntu-based distribution, fixing this out of the box.

I had a previous Peppermint 10, ubuntu-based distro, 64bit lying arond and I tried it, simply select the broadcomm driver at install-time (don't install a later flavour since it has to do with kernel and the broadcomm driver version that it is stable), and you should be set.

In this case, I have no issues anymore with irq conflicts and everything does work out of the box!

I also came across someone telling me mx linux does it as well.

Have fun! The MacBook Air 1,1 is a great machine under linux, it would have been a pity not being able to use it normally, and ubuntu gives it after all a well-deserved life extension!